# Integrate Amobee SDK into Android application

Tags: java, android, flash, air

Did anyone integrated Amobee SDK into Android application on ActionScript or Java?
I have AmobeeTracking.jar file, I have to write native extention to integrate Amobee SDK into Adobe AIR application for Android. But I don't know what to really write. Can anyone help me with this or assist me with some documentation?  http://amobee.com/   Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue in such a way:

1. You need to add to your java native extention project Amobee.jar file, to make classes visible to have oportunity to write code.
2. After you have a complete nativeExt.jar file - you need to make nativeExt.ane file from it, but it will not include Amobee.jar file into it. So to make all ok, you need to do with Amobee.jar - next that writed in this article:   [How to add third-party jar files into my android application jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085189/how-to-add-third-party-jar-files-into-my-android-application-jar-file)  . Thats all.