# How to add third-party jar files into my android application jar file?

Tags: java, android, flash, air, flash-builder

I have an Adobe AIR application for Android. Using for this AIR 3.0 and Flash Builder 4.6. I need to make MyANEFile.ane - which must include 2 external .jar files: Flurry.jar + Tapjoy.jar. But when I made .ane file - it does not work. How can I add this 2 jar files to my main application jar file to  make .ane file properly? Thanks.

It shows me such errors in dalvik:

*01-31 21:37:37.046: I/dalvikvm(12983): Could not find method com.amobee.agency.tracking.AmobeeReceiver.amobeeTracking, referenced from method com.mycompany.extensions.AmobeeInitAmobeeTrackingFunction.call

01-31 21:37:37.046: W/dalvikvm(12983): VFY: unable to resolve static method 317: Lcom/amobee/agency/tracking/AmobeeReceiver;.amobeeTracking (Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)V*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your main extension jar file is extension.jar and you are using code in external.jar. Then you can put the classes from external.jar into extension.jar using the **Java jar tool**:

**jar -xf external.jar**

This will extract the .class files into package folders. If the top-level package is "com", then you can add those to extension.jar with:

**jar -uf extension.jar com**

(Repeat the second command for each top-level package in the external jar.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Eclipse to develop, right click on the project and go to:

Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs

Comment: Thanks, but it does not help(. Still can't find methods in external jar classes.

Answer (score 1):

I was having issue with creating an Android ANE for AdMobs and this is what worked for me.

Do like Flynn suggested and add the jar in the Java Build Path:

[image: Eclipse Java Build Path showing GoogleAdMobsAdsSdk jar in the build path]

Then, the only way I could get the AdMobs jar to play nice in the ANE was to export the Android native jar for the ANE with Export... -> Java -> JAR File and have both "Export all output folders for checked projects" and "Export Java source files and resources" checked:

[image: Eclipse JAR Export with "Export all output folders for checked projects" and "Export Java source files and resources" selected]